# Can't build iphone project in xcode with CATRansform3DMakeRotation

Tags: iphone, core-animation, build-error

I need to use CATRansform3DMakeRotation function in my project, but when I try to compile I get an build error

```
    Undefined symbols:
  "_CATransform3DMakeRotation", referenced from:
```

if I comment the function out the project builds fine.

Any ideas why is this happening?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not enough to include the QuartzCore header file, you also have to right click "Frameworks", select "Add Existing Frameworks" and add "QuartzCore.framework". Problem solved :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the Quartz Core framework to your target.

Find your main target in the left-hand Xcode "Groups and Files" pane. Double-click it, and in the "General" tab you need to hit the "+" button under the Linked Libraries. Choose "QuartzCode.framework" and hit Add.

Now build and you should be good to go.